# Remove device from Find my iPhone

Tags: ipod-touch, mobileme

I recently upgraded my iPod Touch 2nd Gen to an iPhone 4. I have since sold the iPod Touch to someone else. Io no longer want it to show up in the list of devices on the Find My iPhone app, or at https://me.com/find/, but I can't see a way to remove it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems I was being too impatient. After a while, a "(Remove)" link showed up when I expanded the device details on https://me.com/find/